# Tag Maintenance: Remove [consulting]?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that we have a significant number of questions tagged with [consulting](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/consulting), currently 17. I was looking at editing its tag wiki, but to me, it doesn't appear that the majority of the questions are related to consulting in any capacity (and with the way it's being currently used, it reminds me of the old 'client' tag: too general).

Before making a bunch of suggested edits, I want to open the floor, should [consulting](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/consulting) be burninated?

Comment: On the first page of that tag, I see 4 questions that *look* like they could use the tag properly. I'll have to spend more time later to actually check that they're quality, and the tag is appropriate there first though.

Comment: @CanadianLuke - And maybe it doesn't need to be burninated, but a few questions need to be retagged.

Comment: I would definitely agree with that

Answer (score 1):

Burnination is a fickle thing, really. Complete and utter destruction of a tag isn't usually needed unless people are constantly using a tag that should just be blacklisted and keeping up with the volume of questions just isn't enough (like on trilogy sites, or the more active non-trilogy ones).

In this case, no matter what the course of action, there's few enough questions where you can go through them in about 10 minutes and retag as needed. If in doubt, you can always flag the question or bring it up here on meta.